# In what way is the representation not continuous

Tags: general-topology, representation-theory, galois-theory

http://www.math.u-psud.fr/~fontaine/galoisrep.pdf    pp.7-8

Following the definition of a linear representation it states 'if V (an E-vector space) is equipped with a topological structure and if the action of G is continuous, the representation is called continuous.'

I understand the concepts here but then in Example 1.3 (top of the following page) it says that the representation $\rho$ is continuous iff $\operatorname{Ker}(\rho)$ is an open normal subgroup of G.

Is this to do with the topological structure of V?

Comment: The authors are a bit unclear about what $V$ is, but in the previous example they take $V$ to have the discrete topology.  So the inverse image of the identity in $V$ (which is open), i.e., the kernel, must be open for continuity.  Then one can check this is sufficient (you just need the inverse image of any point in $V$ is open).